# Python: заполнить форму ввода на fedresurs.ru

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

необходимо заполнить форму здесь https://fedresurs.ru/messages/IsSearching, т.е. например заполнить его "Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии".
Раньше делал так:

```
driver.execute_script(       "document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').setAttribute('Value','Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии')")
time.sleep(5)
s = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch"]')  # Кнопка поиск
s.click()
```

Но, видимо, на сайте что-то изменилось, и сейчас этот метод не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно заполнять эту форму, какими методами?

Answer (score -1):

Ваш вариант должен работать. id и логика на сайте такие же как описаны.
Не вижу смысла совмещать вызов js из селениума.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').send_keys('Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch').click()
```

Comment: Вот через swnd_keys не работает, но это ладно. Через js поле заполняется, но после того как просходит click по кнопке поиск - данные не обновляются. Т.е. я вставляю текст "Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии", нахожу кнопку, жму click(), страница обновляется - должны остаться только сообщения с выбранным типом, но нет, данные остаются вразнобой